# main cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, dialog

I am new so this is probably simple but I have looked everywhere and cannot figure out the problem. I tried to clean the project, main.xml is in the resources folder but still can't get this to work. All I am trying to do is show a dialog box after the user enters a name and hits the 'show name' button. It really shouldn't be this hard and I have used several examples from online but cannot get it to work. Any help or a point in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance. My first time posting so hopefully I post my question and code correctly.

```
package smartTemps.showName.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class  ShowNameActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
public String name;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    //display dialog with button click

    //create button and register as listener

   Button submitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(main.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.maindialog);
            //builder.setIcon(R.drawable.btn_star);
            dialog.setTitle("User's name");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);

             //get user name
    EditText inputName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    name = inputName.getText().toString();
    TextView userName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userName);
            //set user name label
            userName.setText("Welcome, " + name);

            Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        }       
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of main.this try `NameOfYourActivity.this` to get the instance reference of your Activity to pass into the Dialog. Or even create a little helper function that launches the Dialog with a regular reference to this and the `OnClickListener` can simple call that helper function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `main.xml` file in the `res/layout` folder of your project.

If you have such a file, then check that there are no errors in the xml that is preventing the resource compiler from generating R.java.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(main.this);
```

This is wrong (because your Activity is not called main), you need to pass in either Context or an Activity. If you are going to pass in your Activity then if I have an activity called Activity1:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
```

Within the scope of a class like this:

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
     // Inside here you would put the line above, where this would refer to Activity1
}
```

learn some basic java :)